# Cancel the javascript mousedown event on select in IE 8 not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dom-events

I'm trying to cancel the Javascript `mousedown` event in IE 8.  I have tried a number of different options and combinations.  I have it down to this pure Javascript example that works in IE 11 and Chrome but not in IE 8.

I have tried searching everywhere for an answer and nothing appears to work. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select id="cmb" onmousedown="cancelEvent(event);">
<option>one</option>
<option>two</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
function cancelEvent(e) {

  if (!e) e = window.event;

   e.returnValue = false;
   if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();

   return false;

};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try setting `e.cancelBubble = true;`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I had that before when I was trying JQuery and just tried it again with pure javascript but that didn't fix the issue.  The mousedown is still not canceled.  Thanks for the suggestion!